# Accepting ERC20 tokens with web3.js

Tags: erc-20

I've got an idea for a dApp, but not sure if it's possible or practical. the questions that sound similar that have been answered on here doesn't help with what I'm trying to do, at best, makes it all the more confusing.

I'd like to create my own token and be able to accept it on a website / app where one could spend that specific token, along with some data they'd enter in a text field.

There are not many guides out there that I could find that demonstrate how to accept an ERC20 token with web3.js in a web app. Mostly the tutorials I find are about creating tokens solely for an ico for token swaps. I want to build a web app that accepts them.

Is this possible?

Comment: When you say your DApp, is it a Contract that's accepting ERC20 token, or just a normal account? If it's a normal account then you don't **accept** tokens. Users just **transfer** tokens to you.

Comment: more so along the lines of using the token as a membership payment. so transferring is probably the better word.

web dapp > user sends token along with some text (username) > smart contract takes token and sets and stores usernamevalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its possible to do it, you need to make your dApp compatible with the [Metamask](https://metamask.io/) [extension](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension)

Comment: so a combination of metamask and a webapp with web3.js? any tutorials you can share? would it be easier with ERC2223?

Comment: check links in my answer, in second link you can find Docs on bottom .

Comment: thanks. how about the question of creating a smart contract that gets sets a value for text, possible? how to get that optional field into the metamask UI when sending the token?

Comment: first Q you can't catch value from text by contract,second Q with your dApp you can make it check if this tokens available in a wallet and get select it to do your operation

Comment: is there no way to send text? eg. let's say a user sends one of these tokens through, and I'd want the smart contract to take their text and create a username based off that text

Comment: you will create this smart contract to generate tokens acceptable in your dApp no more else , you need to develop dApp for accept and catche details from owners 'senders' of your tokens

Comment: do you have a guide for accepting and catching details?

Comment: you can do it by JavaScript find in W3School, I hope I have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the Ether and ERC20 tokens WooCommerce Payment Gateway plugin to accept Ether and any ERC20 token of your choice: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ether-and-erc20-tokens-woocommerce-payment-gateway/